# C# ASP .Net MVC 4 variable length route mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need a variable length route mapping in asp.net mvc 3. From my understanding I can map routes like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

But how do I add a variable amount of parameters. The routes in my application have a directory structure starting from a base address something like this:  www.mywebsite.com/root/

Anything followed by root has a directory structure something like this:

www.mywebsite.com/root/directory1/directory2/image.jpg

That would correspond to a mapping something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "root/{path}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "DirectoryBrowser", action = "Browse" } );
```

But I don't know how to set the path parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a wildcard parameter: `"root/{*path}"`

Comment: and how does that map to a method in the controller? what kind of parameter must I add to the method?